# How to remove component styles for unmouned components?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-loader

The problem: component styles keeped when component was unmounted.

In this [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-g1pvv?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue), I unmount(and destroy) `Unused` component, but styles from this component still affect on page.

Background: I'm trying to adapt existed vue codebase for SPA(with vue-router). This problem happens when component for  was changed, but styles from previous component affect on new.
I want to solve it without changes in styles(e.g. creating wrappers).

At the current moment I see only one posible way: change styles.
But I want to have something like [this](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader#useable) (I have not tested it yet).
When component mounted it add styles, when unmounted it remove styles.

Comment: So when the component is there, you do want it to affect styles outside of the component itself right? Or do you only want the styles to be affected within the component?

Comment: "So when the component is there, you do want it to affect styles outside of the component itself right" - right

Comment: I think i can try to use `manualInject`: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-style-loader#options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated answer for style loader version v1.0.0

They added special option injectType:

> injectType
>
> Type: String Default: styleTag
>
> Allows to setup how styles will be injected into the DOM.
>
> Possible values:
>
> styleTag singletonStyleTag lazyStyleTag lazySingletonStyleTag linkTag

### Original answer before v1.0.0 release

Finally i started to use [style-loader/useable](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader#useable) instead of `vue-style-loader` for specific files.
I added extra one rule('useable-styles') for `scss` loader. Here part of my webpack config:

```
export default {
  module: {
    scss: {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      oneOf: {
        'useable-styles': {
          test: /AppHomepage\.scss$/,// pattern for useable styles
          use: {
            'style-loader': {
              loader: 'style-loader/useable',
              options: {
                sourceMap: false,
              },
            },
            'css-loader': { /*...*/ },
            'resolve-url-loader': { /*...*/},
            'sass-loader': { /*...*/},
          },
        },
        'vue-modules': { /*...*/},
        vue: { /*...*/},
        normal: { /*...*/},
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Then I load styles in JS, like this:

```
import styles from './AppHomepage.scss';

// @vue/component
export default {
  name: 'app-homepage',
  beforeCreate() {
    styles.use();
  },
  destroyed() {
    styles.unuse();
  },
};
```

And call `styles.use();` or `styles.unuse();` when it needed and it works.

It is not ideal solution, but it will work as temporary solution and wait for refactoring.

Comment: So which option should I choose in style loader version v1.0.0?

Comment: just use this loader
loader: 'style-loader/useable',

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is now out of date. to use the new style-loader API, something like this via `injectType`:

```
{   
  test: /\.theme\.(sa|sc)ss$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'style-loader',
      options: {attributes: {id: 'theme-sheet'}, injectType: 'lazySingletonStyleTag'}
    },
    {loader: 'css-loader'},
    {loader: 'sass-loader'}
  ]
}
```

docs: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader#lazysingletonstyletag

the `style.use();` / `style.unuse()` remains the same.

Comment: Thank you, i see that in 1.0.0 release they added new feature: injectType which will  solve original issue. Will update my comment above.